# Product weight is not allowed in my custom shipping method in French language in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, localisation, product-weight

I have two stores one is en_US and fr_FR. In en_US store my shipping is fetching data with out any issues. But in fr_FR store my shipping is not working. It shows error like below,

```
[2018-04-10 05:32:02] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Zend_Locale_Exception' with message 'No localized value in 0.1750 found, or the given number does not match the localized format' in /home/Sites/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Format.php:255
```

I checked the reference the number format is not allowed in french language. For english `Weight` format is `0.1750` it's working. But for french the `Weight` format is `0,1750` I can't able to change in backend because `weight` attribute is `Global`. If I change to `Store view`  means no use it's not working. Please tell me how to fix this using language package or tell me any other way to fix this.